# "Rosetta" for switching to native CMake CUDA support

Tags: cmake, cuda, build-automation

I want to switch a CMake-based project of mine to using CMake 3.8 and up's native support for CUDA. I know that, basically, I `enable_language(CUDA)`, then use the regular `add_target` and `add_library` instead of the `cuda_xxx` variants of the same.

However, I'm not sure how to rewrite my code exactly. How do I...:

- Set of global CUDA-related CMake variables , e.g. separable compilation, propagation of host flags?
- Invoke the CUDA equivalent of `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD`and friends?
- Add dependencies on CUDA libraries which are not required by default (e.g. NVTX)
- ... and everything else?

Is there some uniform method to all this, or do I just have to memorize a bunch of new commands?

Answer (score 1):

CMake's native CUDA support works very much in the same way as it does for C and C++ projects.  Using CUDA instead of C++ is a similar process to using C instead of C++.

First of all, you should enable CUDA support in your project by adding:

```
project(myproject LANGUAGES CUDA)
```

This way, you shouldn't need to run `enable_language`, and your CMake cache will not be cluttered with the C and C++ compiler configuration generated by the default implied `project(myproject LANGUAGES C CXX)` you get when you write just `project(myproject)`.

The equivalent of `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` for CUDA is `CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD`, much like how there is also `CMAKE_C_STANDARD`.  Additionally, there is `CMAKE_CUDA_EXTENSIONS` which can be configured to enable / disable compiler specific extensions (i.e. whether to choose `-std=c++14` or `-std=gnu++14`).  It's generally the case that if you see CMake variables of the form `CMAKE_CXX_.....` or `CMAKE_C_.....`, there is an equivalent `CMAKE_CUDA_.....`.  And in general, where you see `CXX` or `C` in variables and properties, there may be a `CUDA` equivalent.

```
set(CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CUDA_EXTENSIONS OFF)
```

One thing to note however, is that these particular variables have target-specific equivalents in the form of target properties (both for C++ and CUDA):

```
set_target_properties(
    myprojectlibrary PROPERTIES
    CUDA_STANDARD 11
    CUDA_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON
    CUDA_EXTENSIONS OFF)
```

As for CUDA-specific features like in the old `FindCUDA`, you should find these as more target properties just like those in the previous example:

```
set_target_properties(
    myprojectlibrary PROPERTIES
    CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON
    CUDA_RESOLVE_DEVICE_SYMBOLS ON)
```

Information about these target properties can be found [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-properties.7.html), searching on the page for "CUDA".

As for linking to third-party libraries, this can be done the same way as it is done for regular C++ projects:

```
target_link_libraries(myprojectlib nvtx)
```

Or if your library isn't defined as a first-class CMake target:

```
target_link_libraries(myprojectlib ${NVTX_LIBRARY})
target_include_directories(myprojectlib PRIVATE ${NVTX_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_compile_definitions(myprojectlib PRIVATE ${NVTX_DEFINES})
```

Lastly, if there are any specific `nvcc` flags required to build your project, these can be set as follows:

```
target_compile_options(myprojectlib PRIVATE --default-stream=per-thread)
```

Note that the global user-configurable `nvcc` flags are also available as the variable `CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS`.

Also note that you may have to change `PRIVATE` to `PUBLIC` in places where you want particular flags / include directories / compile definitions to also be propagated to targets linking to your library, in the case that `myprojectlib` is a library and not an executable, which may or may not be desired depending on how your project is structured.

Comment: And if you want to set C++ compiler options for a CUDA target, do you do that through the `-Xcompiler` NVCC flag, or can you treat the targets as both C++ and CUDA targets at the same time?

Comment: @einpoklum You would have to add `-Xcompiler` flags to `target_compile_options` or `CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS`.  You wouldn't be able to add them as C++ flags directly.